# Proving that $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} +\ldots + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, summation

How would we go about proving that $$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} +\ldots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Comment: Your last term on the left should have * instead of / in the denominator and the right side should have a / in it.

Comment: Please don't edit out your questions. If you feel that your question was answered you can **accept an answer** by clicking the check mark below the vote count. You can only accept one answer, but you can vote them all up or down if you wish to thank the users.

Comment: Very similar question: [Sum of special series: $1/(1\cdot2) + 1/(2\cdot3 )+ 1/(3\cdot4)+\cdots$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255306/sum-of-special-series-1-1-cdot2-1-2-cdot3-1-3-cdot4-cdots)

Comment: Several nice answers have been provided, which show how you can find out what the sum is. But if you were told in your assignment what the sum is supposed to be, you can prove this by induction. In the inductive step you only need to verify that $\frac{n-1}n+\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: User defacing one's questions, probably to cover their tracks. Flagged.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{1}{1\times 2}+\frac{1}{2\times 3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

$=(1-\frac12)+(\frac12-\frac13)+\ldots+(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$

$=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

$=\frac{n}{n+1}$

Comment: This is certainly the most intuitive, and helpful, answer!+1

Comment: The archetypal example of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}\Big)=$$
$$=1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-\Big(\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{1}{j}+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$