# Prove limit of recursive sequence using epsilon-N

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

I have to use the epsilon-N definition of convergence (so not monotone convergence) to prove the limit of the following sequence, and I’m really stuck on how to do so:

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + 1/(n(n+1))

So, essentially,

a<sub>1</sub> = 1/2

a<sub>2</sub> = 1/2 + 1/6

a<sub>3</sub> = 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/12

a<sub>n</sub> = 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/12 + … + 1/(n(n+1))

Intuitively, this converges to 1, so I have my candidate limit. I’m just not sure how to find N or use the epsilon-N method with a recursive sequence like this where each term is a sum including the previous terms.

Comment: Compute the first numbers: $a_1 = 1/2$, $a_2 =2/3$, $a_3 = 3/4$. Can you see a pattern? Can you prove it?

Comment: Yes but how do I use epsilon-N to do so when there’s no explicit formula for a<sub>n</sub>?

Comment: But there *is* an explicit formula for $a_n$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/255308/42969

Comment: Yep, realized as soon as I sent my previous comment, thanks.